# Numerical estimation of $\pi$ with the Buffon's needle

Tags: probability-distributions, numerical-methods

Is there a way of estimating $\pi$ with the Buffon's method without assuming $\pi$ known?

To be more precise: in a Monte Carlo simulation of the [experiment invented by Buffon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle) I would (ideally) generate 2 random numbers with uniform distribution within $[0,1]$ and $[0,\pi]$ respectively (the two numbers being the distance of the center of the needle from the border of the strip and the orientation of the needle). Unfortunately this is sort of cheating because one must already know the value of $\pi$ in order to generate the angle.

A possible reasonable -at least in principle- solution is to work around this problem by generating 2 points in a rectangle and then extract the probability distribution for needle's center and orientation from them (imposing the fixed length of the needle). However analytic calculations to get some usable formulas seem a complete mess to me.

Is there some smarter way of doing that?

Comment: Surely the point of Buffon's method is to calculate $\pi$ empirically... trying to find a way to do it without ever involving a random sample will necessarily be tautological. You "generate" the angle by physically chucking a needle at a grid. Generating 2 points in a rectangle doesn't help you, because there are constraints on the points - they will necessarily be unit distance apart, meaning that the only free parameter left is... the angle between them, which will be in $[0,2\pi]$, taking you back to square one.

Comment: @JoshuaPepper yes, conservation of information should hold here too (not to be tautological) :) I'll try to make the question clearer.

Comment: You may want to check http://www.cut-the-knot.org/fta/Buffon/buffon9.shtml#Sincerity

Answer (score 1):

A simple Monte Carlo approach to estimate the value of $\pi$ is to generate random numbers $(x_n)$ with uniform distribution in $[0,1]$ and to compute four times the proportion of pairs $(x_{2n-1},x_{2n})$ such that $x_{2n-1}^2+x_{2n}^2\leqslant1$. The error when using $2n$ points is $\Theta(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of generating two points uniformly in a rectangle is a good first shot ... but rapidly becomes a nightmare.

Instead, generate $x, y$ uniformly randomly in $[-1, 1]$. If $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 > 1$ or $r = 0$, reject them and start over.

Use this to generate two $xy$-pairs, and then treat their center point as the needle center, and their difference as the needle's direction vector. (Also: If the points happen to be identical, reject them and start over.)

Does that make sense? No need to know $\pi$ up front; all you need is to be able to square numbers.

Comment: Perhaps it is ... but I don't see why. I was trying to answer @cherbert's question about how to generate a random angle without knowing $\pi$ a priori. Did's answer seems to be a scheme for estimating $\pi$ that could perhaps be transformed into Buffon's approach with a little thinking. But I don't see the correspondence offhand.